# does unhandled postMessage leak memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, postmessage

I have a page that may work as a standalone webpage or within a special "watchdog frame" to which it would be sending messages periodically using `window.top.postMessage('message', '*');`

The problem is if the page is loaded as standalone webpage, there will be nothing to capture these messages. Users can be expected to hold that page open for hours or even days at a time.

Do these uncaught messages just vanish without a trace, or do they get queued or something like that, leaking the memory?

Comment: `postMessage` causes a `MessageEvent` to be dispatched, similarly to how a click on a document would trigger a `MouseEvent`. Why do you expect a memory leak?

Comment: @RobW: I've never used the postMessage mechanism before, and I simply didn't know what lies behind it - an event, a queue, a socket? - post that as an answer and I'll accept, "it behaves just the same as events" is exactly what I hoped to hear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`postMessage` initiates a `MessageEvent` on the target, which is not more special than a regular `onload` event.

The event itself does not cause any memory leaks. You can create memory leaks by introducing unwanted closures, but that also applies to regular functions:

```
window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false);
function messageHandler(event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    };
    img.src = event.data.some.property.deep.ly.nested.obj.bad.coding.style.src;
}
```

What's the problem? The image's `onload` handler inserts the picture in the document when it's loaded. However, because of the closure, the `event` object cannot be freed, and the big `event.data` object will still occupy memory.

Another way to introduce a memory leak (same-origin only) is to save the value of `event.source` (preventing the frame's view from being GC'd when the frame is removed):

```
var stupidity = [];
window.onmessage = function(event) {
    stupidity.push(event.source);
};
```

Comment: So, how does one properly free an object that is sent during a postmessage? e.g. something=new object, postmessage(something). Then - for whatever reason - the postmessage is not handled, but an application destroy is called. The postmessage queue needs "something" to ensure the internal queue and special objects are freed if they are not handled. Or is this simply considered incredibly bad practice?